# PHP code, last line won't run without errors

Tags: php

I'm running this code:

```
<?php
 get_header(); ?>
<div id="fullwidth" class="main-fullwidth main-col-full">
        <?php if ( have_posts() ):
                while ( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                <?php endwhile;
        endif; ?>
</div><!-- #fullwidth -->
<?php
$data = $_GET['data'];
$params = [];
parse_str(base64_decode(strtr($data, ['-' => '+', '_' => '/'])), $params);

$entry = GFAPI::get_entry($params["orderid"]);
$url = $entry["source_url"];

$query_str = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($query_str, $query_params);
$parent_id = ($query_params["workflow_parent_entry_id"]);

$form_id = "6";
$parent_entry = GFAPI::get_entry($parent_id);
$step_id = "39";

$api = new Gravity_Flow_API( $form_id );
$api->send_to_step( $parent_entry, $step_id );

$result = GFAPI::delete_entry("224");


?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

and one of the last lines,

```
$result = GFAPI::delete_entry("224");
```

this line will only work if I comment out these lines (13 lines above the mentioned line):

```
$data = $_GET['data'];
    $params = [];
    parse_str(base64_decode(strtr($data, ['-' => '+', '_' => '/'])), $params);
    
    $entry = GFAPI::get_entry($params["orderid"]);
    $url = $entry["source_url"];
    
    $query_str = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
    parse_str($query_str, $query_params);
    $parent_id = ($query_params["workflow_parent_entry_id"]);
    
    $form_id = "6";
    $parent_entry = GFAPI::get_entry($parent_id);
    $step_id = "39";
    
    $api = new Gravity_Flow_API( $form_id );
    $api->send_to_step( $parent_entry, $step_id );
```

However code doesn't spit out any errors. I'm grasping for straws here, what could be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: You say *last line won't run without errors*, so something must happen, do you get any message or how do you know it's failing?

Comment: Because that line is supposed to delete an entry, it doesn't. If I comment those lines above, it does delete.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about working with API's. One thing I do notice is that you are not error handling. Try checking if the the api does what you are trying, although you can see if it is working or not you could specify conditions to your last line of code to see why it is not working.

This is an example

```
<?php
if($api->send_to_step( $parent_entry, $step_id )) {
    echo "Working!" . $parent_entry . ' - ' . $step_id;
} else {
    echo "Not working!" . $parent_entry . ' - ' . $step_id;
};
```

With this you can see if it is getting executed. And what the values of the two variables are. I hope this might help you out a bit.